# Getting the value from dropdownlist and display it on the next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am new to asp.net and I am making a Registration Page and I made a dropdownlist and the items have been displaying on the dropdownlist on Page1. [page1 and dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MITD5.png)
This is my Page2 which is my Transaction page,[transaction page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3vv7.png)
As you can see, The names and memberID has been displayed but the Selected item from the dropdownlist on the Registration Page is still "Silver". When I'm choosing the other Items, it is always stays as **silver**.

**Registration.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["txtFN"] = txtFN.Text;
    Session["txtLN"] = txtLN.Text;
    Session["txtB"] = txtB.Text;
    Session["txtMemID"] = lblMemID.Text;
    Session["SelectedMST"] = SelectedMST.SelectedValue;

    Response.Redirect("Transaction.aspx");
}
```

**Transaction.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lblFN.Text = Session["txtFN"].ToString();
        lblLN.Text = Session["txtLN"].ToString();
        lblMemID.Text = Session["txtMemID"].ToString();
        MST.Text = Session["SelectedMST"].ToString();
        
        CreateList();

    }
}
```

I thought it would work like the textbox but I tried doing **SelectedMST.SelectedValue or SelectedItem** but the result, it is still Silver on the LABEL even if I selected Gold or Platinum from the Registration page.
I want the selected Item from dropdownlist is to be displayed on the Transaction Page's **label** which ID is "MST".

Answer (score 0):

Remember, a dropdown list can have 2 values - the hidden value, and the display value (2 possible columns).

You find this tends to work the best:

So, say this markup:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName"
            >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

And this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadDrop();
    }

    void LoadDrop()
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();                    
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                DropDownList1.DataSource = rstData;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

And then thus:

```
        Debug.Print(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);  // get text value
        Debug.Print(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value); // get hidden "value"
```

So, in your case, then  you want the text value, so then try/use this:

```
   Session["SelectedMST"] = SelectedMST.SelectedItem.Text;
```

That should pull/get the text value, and place into session.

If you use selectedValue, you get the "hidden" value, and not the text.

Since this can be confusing?

Then I always use this for text

```
   Session["SelectedMST"] = SelectedMST.SelectedItem.Text;
```

and for value, I use this:

```
   Session["SelectedMST"] = SelectedMST.SelectedItem.Value;
```

So, the above format tends to "reduce" confusing.